# Help with exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

> In airport A, the time between the arrivals of flights coming from the UK is exponentially distributed, with a mean of an hour.
>
> 1. What is the probability that more than three flights arrive within an hour?
> 2. If we choose 30 separate 1 hour intervals, what is the probability that no interval is a siege of more than 3 arrivals?
> 3. If the probability that no flights arrive during a time interval is 0.1, what is its length?

The mean is $1/\lambda=1\Leftrightarrow\lambda=1$ per hour.
Number 3 is straightforward. I want to find $t$ such that $\int_0^te^{-x}dx=0.1$

I am stuck with the rest, though. What I can do is transform this into a Poisson distribution problem so as to get$$P(X>3)=1-P(X\leq3)=1-\sum_{i=0}^3\frac{e^{-1}}{i!}$$
and then for 2) do $(P(X\leq3))^{30}$, but I am not sure if this is what should be done..

Any guidance? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time between arrivals is i.i.d. exponential with rate $\lambda$, then the number of arrivals within a fixed time interval of length $t$ is $Poisson\left(\lambda t\right)$. Here $\lambda=1$.

Thus, you are first looking for $P\left(N_1 > 3\right)$, which is indeed $1 - \sum_{i\leq 3} \frac{e^{-1}}{i!}$. For the second part, you use the fact that any two non-overlapping increments of a Poisson process are independent, which justifies $\left(1-P\left(N_1 > 3\right)\right)^{30}$ because you are looking at $30$ "separate" (I presume this means "disjoint") intervals. For the last part, let $T$ be the time of the first arrival; observe that

$$P\left(N_t = 0\right) = P\left(T > t\right) = e^{-t},$$

so you are looking for $t = -\log\left(0.1\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I think that we want $t=-\ln(0.9)$, since no planes have arrived yet, i.e we want $P(T<t)$, right?

Comment: $T$ is the time until the first arrival, so if no planes have arrived by time $t$, the first arrival time must take place after $t$, hence $T > t$.

Comment: sorry, but i am not following you. let our random variable be $T$, which is the time between two arrivals. we start counting time ($t=0$) when the first flight arrives.
if the the time until the next arrival is $t$, then no arrival has occurred before $t$, and I want to find $t$ such that the probability that no airplane comes until $t$ is $0.1$, so I am looking for $P(T<t)=0.1$.

Comment: ah, sorry, i had a wrong idea of the exponential distribution.. thank you!

Comment: If no arrival has occurred before $t$, then the time of the first arrival should be _after_ $t$, hence $T>t$. Also, we start counting time at $t=0$, not when the first flight arrives. Initially $N_0 = 0$, and $T$ is the (random) time of the first arrival.

Comment: hey! i have another question: is there no equivalent to the Poisson probabilities that we have calculated in exponential distribution form?

Comment: What exactly does that mean? The Poisson distribution models integer-valued quantities, and the exponential distribution models continuous positive numbers. The relationship between Poisson processes and exponential distributions is that the latter model the times in between two Poisson arrivals.

Comment: I meant it in the sense that we operate on the time instead of the number of arrivals. A wrong take of mine that should clarify my question is that I tried to model (a) as a Bernoulli trial $$1-\sum_{n=0}^{3}\left(\frac{3!}{n!\left(3-n\right)!}p^{n}\left(1-p\right)^{3-n}\right)$$with$$p=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x}dx$$

Comment: The question is why the Bernoulli trials are independent. It is because, in a Poisson process, the numbers of arrivals in disjoint intervals of time are independent from each other. The success probability then has to do with the number of trials in an interval, so it is a Poisson probability, but many events related to the number of trials can be converted into events related to the time in between trials, in which case the exponential distribution would be useful.